# Does Bluray have NTFS support?

Tags: ntfs, blu-ray

Does Bluray have NTFS support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, only ISO 9660 and UDF

Answer (score 3):

The file systems supported by Blu-Ray:

- ISO 9660

  - Joliet
  - Rock Ridge / SUSP
  - El Torito
  - Apple ISO 9660 Extensions
- Universal Disk Format (UDF)

  - Mount Rainier